# Creating new users without resetting current user session

Tags: parse-platform

In my Parse web app, I have a user management page that is accessible to administrators. This page allows admins to create new user accounts.

To create the accounts, I use `Parse.User.signUp()`.

It works great, but it has the nasty side effect of resetting the current user session, which logs out the admin who created the new user account.

This is actually the [documented](https://www.parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.User.html#signUp) behaviour of `User.signUp()`:

> This will create a new Parse.User on the server, and also persist the session in localStorage so that you can access the user using #current.

But I want to create new users without changing the current user. How do I do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Before creating the new user account with `User.signUp`, save the current user's `sessionToken`. Then, once the new user has been created, restore the session with `User.become`:

```js
var sessionToken = Parse.User.current().getSessionToken();

Parse.User.signUp(username, password).then(function(newUser) {
    Parse.User.become(sessionToken);
});
```

Comment: @pascual_bourque I used your code and gets this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Parse.User.become is not a function`

Comment: This should work as-is in Parse Cloud Code. If you're doing this client-side, make sure to import the Parse module properly...

Comment: @pascal_bourque I've just tried it, but it doesn't works, here is the code (AngularJS) https://bitbucket.org/snippets/delpo/Bj6px

Comment: @pascal_bourque Solved! I was using an old API version (1.1)

Answer (score 0):

I can create a 'Parse Cloud' method that allows you use the 'Master Key' and call it from the SDK using the Cloud.

```
Parse.Cloud.define('salvarUsuario', function(request, response) {

  var nomeCompleto = request.params.nomeCompleto;
  var Email = request.params.Email;
  var Username = request.params.Username;
  var cpf = request.params.cpf;
  var Password = request.params.Password;
  var funcionarioBool = request.params.funcionarioBool;
  var ativo = request.params.ativo;
  var primeiroAcesso = request.params.primeiroAcesso;
  var tipoAcesso = request.params.tipoAcesso;
  var medicoBool = request.params.medicoBool;

  //Parâmetros de controle
  var fotoSelecionada = request.params.fotoSelecionada;

  var usuario = new Parse.User();

  usuario.set("nomeCompleto", nomeCompleto);
  usuario.set("email", Email);
  usuario.set("username", Username);
  usuario.set("cpf", cpf);
  usuario.set("password", Password);
  usuario.set("funcionarioBool", funcionarioBool);
  usuario.set("ativo", ativo);
  usuario.set("primeiroAcesso", primeiroAcesso);
  usuario.set("tipoAcesso", tipoAcesso);
  usuario.set("medicoBool", medicoBool);

  if(medicoBool) {
    var medicoId = request.params.medico;
    var Medico = Parse.Object.extend("Medico");
    var medicoPointer = Medico.createWithoutData(medicoId);
    usuario.set("medico", medicoPointer);
  }

  if(fotoSelecionada) {
    var bytes = request.params.bytesFoto;
    var file = new Parse.File("foto.png", bytes, "image/png");

    usuario.set("foto", file);
  }

  usuario.save(null, {
      useMasterKey: true,
      success: function(salvoUsuario){
          // The user was saved correctly
          response.success("1");

      },
      error: function(error){
          response.error("Erro ao criar novo usuário");
      }
  });
});
```