# Swift OSX - Parse.com - Save new user without changing

Tags: swift, macos, session, parse-platform

I am trying to add new users on my database using Parse. I can't save the new user directly without calling the sign up method, but after signing up the user changes to the user that was signed up and I want to keep the same user that was using the software before.

I found on this link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27946748/creating-new-users-without-resetting-current-user-session) in StackOverflow that I need to save the previews session and after the new user sign up process I can call the method `become` to recover the user that was being used before using the saved session, but it is returning me an error: `[Error]: invalid session token (Code: 209, Version: 1.15.3)`. Here is the code:

Usuario.swift

```
import Foundation

import Parse

class Usuario: PFUser {

    @NSManaged var nome: String?
}
```

The action to save the new user

```
@IBAction func adicionarGerenciadorButtonClicked(_ sender: NSButton) {

    let gerenciador = Usuario()

    gerenciador.nome = nomeGerenciadorTextField.stringValue
    gerenciador.username = emailGerenciadorTextField.stringValue
    gerenciador.email = emailGerenciadorTextField.stringValue
    gerenciador.password = senhaGerenciadorSecureTextField.stringValue

    let gerenciadorTokenAtual = Usuario.current()!.sessionToken
    print(gerenciadorTokenAtual)

    gerenciador.signUpInBackground(block: {
            (success, error) -> Void in

            do {
                try Usuario.become(gerenciadorTokenAtual!)
            } catch {

            }

            if error == nil {
                self.gerenciadores.append(gerenciador)

                self.nomeGerenciadorTextField.stringValue = ""
                self.emailGerenciadorTextField.stringValue = ""
                self.senhaGerenciadorSecureTextField.stringValue = ""
            } else {
                self.mostrarErro(mensagem: "Erro", informativo: "Houve um erro ao tentar salvar o gerenciador")
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a 'Parse Cloud' method that allows me use the 'Master Key'

```
Parse.Cloud.define('salvarUsuario', function(request, response) {

  var nomeCompleto = request.params.nomeCompleto;
  var Email = request.params.Email;
  var Username = request.params.Username;
  var cpf = request.params.cpf;
  var Password = request.params.Password;
  var funcionarioBool = request.params.funcionarioBool;
  var ativo = request.params.ativo;
  var primeiroAcesso = request.params.primeiroAcesso;
  var tipoAcesso = request.params.tipoAcesso;
  var medicoBool = request.params.medicoBool;

  //Parâmetros de controle
  var fotoSelecionada = request.params.fotoSelecionada;

  var usuario = new Parse.User();

  usuario.set("nomeCompleto", nomeCompleto);
  usuario.set("email", Email);
  usuario.set("username", Username);
  usuario.set("cpf", cpf);
  usuario.set("password", Password);
  usuario.set("funcionarioBool", funcionarioBool);
  usuario.set("ativo", ativo);
  usuario.set("primeiroAcesso", primeiroAcesso);
  usuario.set("tipoAcesso", tipoAcesso);
  usuario.set("medicoBool", medicoBool);

  if(medicoBool) {
    var medicoId = request.params.medico;
    var Medico = Parse.Object.extend("Medico");
    var medicoPointer = Medico.createWithoutData(medicoId);
    usuario.set("medico", medicoPointer);
  }

  if(fotoSelecionada) {
    var bytes = request.params.bytesFoto;
    var file = new Parse.File("foto.png", bytes, "image/png");

    usuario.set("foto", file);
  }

  usuario.save(null, {
      useMasterKey: true,
      success: function(salvoUsuario){
          // The user was saved correctly
          response.success("1");

      },
      error: function(error){
          response.error("Erro ao criar novo usuário");
      }
  });
});
```